# Improved step down SQL query without many IF/ELSE blocks

Tags: php, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Consider a sample table with these rows:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | postcode | value |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | A1A3A3   | one   |
|  2 | A1A3A4   | two   |
|  3 | A1A3B    | three |
|  4 | A1A3C    | four  |
|  5 | A1A3D    | five  |
|  6 | A1A3     | six   |
|  7 | A1A      | seven |
|  8 | A1       | eight |
+----+----------+-------+
```

My goal is to perform a query, whereby it steps down through the postcode column until an **exact** match is found.

Let's say my starting query parameter is `A1A3E9`. The expected return value, based on the sample table, would be `six`. It is important to note, that each step down, I remove one character from the end of the starting query parameter.

So first I would try and find a match for `A1A3E9`, and then `A1A3E`, and then `A1A3` and so forth.

Currently, I achieve this simply with a series of IF/ELSE blocks, like this:

```sql
IF
    EXISTS (
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost6_1
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost6_2
    END
ELSE IF
    EXISTS (
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost5_1
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost5_2
    END
ELSE IF
    EXISTS (
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost4_1
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost4_2
    END
ELSE IF
    EXISTS (
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost3_1
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost3_2
    END
ELSE IF
    EXISTS (
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost2_1
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT value FROM table
        WHERE postcode=:userPost2_2
    END
```

Note that I am using parameter binding in PHP, so just for context, my parameter bindings ultimately look like this:

```php
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost6_1', "A1A3E9", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost6_2', "A1A3E9", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost5_1', "A1A3E",  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost5_2', "A1A3E",  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost4_1', "A1A3",   PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost4_2', "A1A3",   PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost3_1', "A1A",    PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost3_2', "A1A",    PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost2_1', "A1",     PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':userPost2_2', "A1",     PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I do not have have any concerns so far as performance is concerned, as I have an index on the postcode column (which contains 40,000+ rows). My concern is purely that this is visually, an unpleasant query to look at.

**My question:** Is there a cleaner way to write this query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
where 'A1A3E9' like t.postcode + '%'
order by t.postcode desc;
```

The only issue is that your multiple `if` statements are probably faster.  Getting performance is a real challenge with this type of problem.  One method uses multiple `join`s:

```
select v.pc, coalesce(t0.value, t1.value, t2.value, . . . )
from (values ('A1A3E9')) v(pc) left join
     t t0
     on t0.postcode = v.pc left join
     t t1
     on t1.postcode = t0.postcode is null and
        (case when len(v.pc) > 1 then left(v.pc, len(v.pc) - 1) end) left join
     t t2
     on t1.postcode is null and
        t2.postcode = (case when len(v.pc) > 2 then left(v.pc, len(v.pc) - 2) end) left join
     . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first spool all the potentially matching rows, eg:

```
select *
into #matches
from t
where postcode like 'AI%'
```

This can use an index on postcode and so should be cheap.  Then *whatever* query you run against the matches will just operate over this subset.  Even writing a UDF that compares postcode to a literal, eg:

```
select top 1 *
from #matches
order by dbo.NumberOfMatchingCharacters(postcode,'A1A3E9') desc
```